# Lost focus event is not occured for ListBox.ItemTemplate during SelectedItem chaged event of the hosting Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

there is the following definition of a listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource ="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedValue ="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel >
                <CheckBox IsChecked ="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Text ="{Binding Description, Mode = TwoWay}" LostFocus="OnLostFocus"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the problem that I have faced that `LostFocus` event is not appeared when a selected index of the ListBoxChanged (for example by pressing arrow up on a selected item), but occures when I do mouse clicks on the other ListboxItems.
How to make it work consitantly?

Comment: Are you after checking when its changed or that it actually lost focus, because while you potentially still can use arrows change the selected item, it clearly still has focus, and so the code is right.

Comment: You are right. In may case the text box is visible, but not in focus. any ideas how can I trigger my Lostfocus logic on selection changed?

Comment: Put it in the "selectionChanged" event.. where it would be if thats what you want it to do, eg change when the selected item changes..